# Iterating through YAML objects

Tags: python, pandas, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to read a YAML file and print out the list but having issues iterating through the objects

**YAML**

```
-ingestion:

  elastic_id: census_acs_us_table_1_2019
  python_configurations:
    sequences:
    - '0001'
    - '0002'
    - '0003'
    - '0004'
    - '0007'
    - '0008'
```

I tried the following:

```
df_list = []

for i in glob.glob("file.yml"):
    with open(i) as yaml_file:
        config_yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
     
    elastic_id = config_yaml_data['ingestion']['elastic_id']
    config_df_list = []
    for seq in config_yaml_data['ingestion']['python_configurations']['sequences']:
        config_df_list.append(seq_cols_df[seq])
    config_df = pd.concat(config_df_list)
    config_df['elastic_id'] = elastic_id
    df_list.append(config_df)
results = pd.concat(df_list)
```

**Output**

```
KeyError: 'ingestion'
```

What can I change to get this to print my results?

Comment: Yaml is really finicky: in your yaml file, try `- ingestion:` instead of `-ingestion:` (add space after the dash). There might also be some other issues in the yaml file itself (did not test fully), but I think you need to validate your yaml. Once you've loaded it, take a look at the `config_yaml_data` dictionary, that will give you hints as to why things aren't working

Comment: @sacuL The code implies that the root object ought to be a dictionary, not a list. So it should probably be just `ingestion:`, not `- ingestion:`.